# how to get history in a date range by given key

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

As the question in the title, and I know we have getHistoryForKey fucntion which returns all results

but wondering how do we get the status of the blockchain at a certain date time? or, maybe how to get the history of a date range by a given key

Comment: for down-voters, please let me know what's the reason

Comment: Range query cant be applied on history datastore,only history for the key can be fetched as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on to implement a functionality like that. For instance, what I can say is you have to always start from the last block that has value of key k, no matter what is your range. So, higher the difference between your first argument of range, and current time, poorer the performance. You can check [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8509388).